# Gitlab custom hook not running

Tags: linux, git, centos, gitlab

We have Gitlab installed on the same server as a dev/staging copy of our test project. Two of us have local working copies with Gitlab as a remote, and are able to push/pull to Gitlab successfully. We also have Gitlab set as a remote in the staging copy of the project, and pulling from Gitlab works there manually as well.

However, when creating a custom hook for Gitlab (as described [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html)), the hook simply fails to run with no errors. The content of the hook is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Inside post_receive hook"
cd /path/to/staging/copy
git pull gitlab master
```

...where `/path/to/staging/copy` is the staging location of the project. Here's the ownership & permissions of the hook:

`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 git git 114 Mar 30 10:28 post_receive`

When pushing from my working copy to Gitlab, this hook should run, but it doesn't -- the staging copy is not updated, the echo message isn't shown, and the push results message doesn't show any errors.

I have tried a few tips from SO answers regarding setting/unsetting environment variables, and they didn't help. I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know why the custom hook isn't running?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this was my fault. I mis-named the hook with an underscore instead of a dash. Hook now fires appropriately.