# custom_hooks not working on gitlab/docker

Tags: gitlab, githooks, self-hosting

I use a docker image of gitlab, https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab/ on a synology nas to manage our pipeline dev. 
I plan to deploy any push in the master branch to a production folder, where all our software looks to load scripts/ plugins.

To deploy to the production server, on the same server but outside the docker image.
the production folder is set as a clone of the server

```
git clone /gitserver/path /prod/folder/path
```

all works as planned

then, I've tryied to use a custom_hook for a repo as described on the documentation here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html
the custom hooks is called "post-update", chmod +x and rights allowed to anyone (for testing). here is the content of the hook

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "********** publishing to prod *********" 
cd /prod/folder/path
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
echo "********** Publish to prod complete *********"
```

when I push to the git server, nothing happened. 
If I run manually the post-update script, all work as espected so it seems that the problem come from gitlab custom_hooks support.
I have seen many posts about problems with custom hooks but none of them helps me

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1742

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38193

[Gitlab custom hook not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350152/gitlab-custom-hook-not-running)

how can I make custom_hooks works ?